# Better way to get index of ordered queryable list at entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-order-by, indexof, iqueryable, iorderedqueryable

Are there any way to get index of ordered queryable without getting all items?

My code seems to be killer of network traffic:

```
 public virtual async Task<int> GetIndexOfQueryable<TOrderKey>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExp, Predicate<TEntity> findIndexExp, Expression<Func<TEntity, TOrderKey>> orderbyExp, bool descending)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = whereExp != null ? DbSet.Where(whereExp) : DbSet.AsQueryable();
        if (orderbyExp != null)
            query = !descending ? query.OrderBy(orderbyExp) : query.OrderByDescending(orderbyExp);
        return (await query.ToListAsync()).FindIndex(findIndexExp);
    }
```

Comment: What about `query.Where(findIndexExp).OrderBy(orderbyExp).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: It doesn't give me index of ordered list.